# Flash socket policy file request denied by HTTP proxy

Tags: flash, sockets, proxy

We want to serve Flash socket policy files through port 80, as port 843 cannot be used due to security restrictions. However, it seems the policy file request is not delivered to the server, because a proxy detects it is not requested through the HTTP protocol.

When we test it, the client receives:

```
<p class="red">Request denied by WatchGuard HTTP Proxy.</p>
<p><b> Reason: </b> request-line invalid line='&lt;policy-file-request/&gt;\x0d\x0a' </p>
<p>Please contact your administrator for assistance.</p>
```

It seems it is not possible (anymore?) to serve socket policy files through HTTP. Is there another way to circumvent this issue?

Answer (score 2):

By using SecureSocket (which sends the policy file request over SSL) and SSL termination on our reverse proxy server, I was able to solve this issue